# Getting a what i believe to be a webclient error in C#, Need help Please

Tags: c#, runtime-error, webclient

Okay so i am fairly new to programming and was told to just start acouple projects and google/ask if i need hep so here i am, im making a program that will download and run a file from the internet and when i run the release app i get this error http://gyazo.com/7b017f0ed550af3b86b24ad480db8fe8 so i press the details and it give me this long error report thing http://pastebin.com/Ag7u9gBZ i dont seem to have enough knowledge to be able to read and debug it, and i am very confussed, from what i see it has to do with system.io and webclient and path or something i dont know.

```
private void startBotToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string filepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\" + "Minecraft.exe";
    string direct_exe_from_url = "http://rs542p2.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=1764003915&filename=Minecraft.exe&cookie=F2CB284BDC9920808D8494CA4EB46F0935AB22D79EC69D6D130C21FB6AD2A0A1EB413347302A46C5FB1A39599DF740D6&directstart=1";

    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
    wc.DownloadFile(direct_exe_from_url, filepath);

    Process.Start(filepath);
}
```

Comment: here is the code snipplet of that part of the program http://pastebin.com/h2Tdpaku

Comment: Does the folder "Downloaded Files" exist in your AppData folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting a `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` so I would guess that this: `C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Roaming\Downloaded Files\` directory does not exist.

You can use the [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx) method to create the directory before putting the downloaded file in there, e.g:

```
string directoryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\";
string filepath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppData") + "\\Downloaded Files\\" + "Minecraft.exe";

if (!Directory.Exists(directoryPath)) 
{
     Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryPath);
}

string direct_exe_from_url = "http://rs542p2.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=download&fileid=1764003915&filename=Minecraft.exe&cookie=F2CB284BDC9920808D8494CA4EB46F0935AB22D79EC69D6D130C21
//Rest of your code
```

Comment: i get this error when i put that code in http://gyazo.com/e74204983d489563499eac35e8ad9ccb im confussed that is c# right?

Comment: No problem - you can also put `using System.IO;` at the top of your .cs file (you should see some other `using` statements up the top) if you don't want to fully qualify things all the time. Please also consider marking your question as answered if you've gotten around your issue :-)